# local (not Noetherian) domain satisfying a.c.c. on radical ideals and satisfying d.c.c on prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, homological-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a local (not Noetherian) domain satisfying a.c.c. on radical ideals and satisfying d.c.c on prime ideals.

Then is the Krull dimension of $R$  finite ?

EDIT: Note that if our ring is a Valuation ring, then due to the comparability of any two ideals, the ring must have only finitely many prime ideals if it has to satisfy ac.c. on radical ideals, hence the dimension would be finite.

Comment: I would say that the general case is false because there are rings of infinite dimension such that every ordered chain of prime ideals is finite. You should look for examples, maybe some of them satisfy acc and dcc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if $R$ is a valuation ring, then with the acc and dcc on prime ideals, it is of finite dimension. I tried this :

Because of the dcc and the fact that the set $\mathcal{P}$ of prime ideals of $R$ is totally ordered, there exists a $p_0$ such that $\forall p \in \mathcal{P}, p_0 \subset p$. If we consider $\mathcal{P} \setminus \{ p_0 \}$, it has a minimal element too, say $p_1$. Thus we construct a chain $p_0 \subset p_1 \subset \cdots $ which must be finite due to the acc. Then there is a finite number of prime ideals, so the dimension is finite.

Comment: I don't think you even need the d.c.c. assumption ...

Comment: It seems necessary to show that there is a minimal element in $\mathcal{P} \setminus \{ p_0, ... , p_k \}$.